# Divide text in multiple lines in a single Excel cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cell, line-breaks

So i've been searching how to divide text depending on its length but couldn't find anything.

My question is : In Excel using vba code, is it possible to divide a line of text into several lines in a single cell?

I don't have access to the text itself, it's inserted via a query from an Access Database. This being said, I can't really use the linebreak character "Chr(10)" to help me out.

I'm thinking of a way to distinguish if the text length is greater than a certain number of letters, it could be splited in 2 (or more actually) and then concatonate it using the linebreak character.

I hope my question/request is clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found 2-3 vba techniques which could be helpful but have no idea which is best for you. could you add link to any print screen of your data range- how is it organised. Or add a table layout in your question for better understanding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just for display purposes, then I think there is an easier method. You could set the column width to a width you like and format the cells in that column to Wrap Text.

There are two settings on your Querytable that you need to pay attention to. "Adjust column width" is unchecked by default and you need to check it. If you don't, Excel will make the column bigger and the fact that you have Wrap Text checked won't matter. "Preserve cell formatting" is checked by default and needs to remain checked. That will ensure that Wrap text stays checked for that column.

Setting the column width won't guarantee that you get a specific number of characters unless you use a fixed font. But if you just want to get close, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall VB correctly you need to use vbLf

As in:

```
Dim range
Dim i
Dim split_value
Dim splits() as Variant

range = Range("A1")
split_value = 15
i = 0

' Split them
While( Len(range.Value) > split_value )
    ReDim Preserve splits(i)
    splits(i) = Mid(range.Value, 1, split_value)
    range.Value = Mid(range.Value, split_value + 1)
    i = i + 1
Wend

' Join them
For c = LBound(splits) To UBound(splits)
    range.Value = range.Value & vbLf & splits(c)
Next c
```

Comment: Since i don't have access to the text itself, i can't have the two parts in a string format as you showed, it's then a bit complicated. When the text is inserted in the worksheet, I could retrieve the text and maybe split it?